# Why the Add method of my dbContext would be adding 2 parent entities and 1 child entity causing PK constrain error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Short version:
When doing "myDbContext.Add(Entity)" I got 2 entities added, one I just created and one I query just before, but also add to the dbContext a child entity (related to the first entity I query for) and seems the EF isn't tracking them as existing because is trying to insert both the Parent and the Child entity.

I can't add specific code because of policies but, basically I'm doing something like:

```
using (var db = new MyEntitiesContext()) 
{
    /*don't know why, but code was already like this, 
    has some method which returns list of 
    SomeEntity type even knowing will have only 1 object*/

    List<SomeEntity> entities = new List<SomeEntity>
    entities = SomeMethod.SearchEntities(id);
    SomeEntity current = entities.FirstOrDefault();
    SomeEntity newOne = new SomeEntity();

    //Then notice I use some of the values (all of them are int/string/date)
    //from the "current" object to populate the "newOne"
    newOne.Id =  (from p in db.SomeEntities select p.Id).Max() + 1;
    newOne.SomeDateValue = current.SomeDateValue;
    newOne.someStringValue =  current.someStringValue;
    .
    . //add some other values which doesnt' seem relevant to the issue
    .
    db.SomeEntity(newOne);
    db.SaveChanges();           

}
```

For some reason the SaveChanges method causes an exception related to an child entity violating an PK constrain.

After debugging and doing some "watches" I noticed that my dbContext object "db" was actually holding 2 entities of SomeEntity, the "newOne" and the "current" I could it notice because of the "Count" value of the db.SomeEntity.Local property.

For some reason (bad design/understanding) when doing:

```
db.SomeEntity.Add(newOne)
```

the "current" instance was added as well alongside a child entity "status", so the SaveChanges() tries to re-insert an existing "status" entity (besides the existing "current" entity), and that was throwing the exception in the SaveChanges() method.

Seems I can fix this issue by detaching the objects that are causing the conflict,which are the "current" entity and it's child entity "status" from the dbContext object, but

why is that happening ? or how can I avoid that ?

My only assumpion is that some reference when assigning values from "current" to "newOne" could possible causing the behavior, notice the "status" child entity isn't being assigned from "current" to "newOne", I've tried to assigned using a new instance of "status" entity and left it as null but none of those fix the issue.

**note**:I've tried to query for the "current" object in a different "using" block, but the issue persisted.

**note 2**:Code compiles and gets executed well until SaveChanges method, sample above isn't the actual code but a shortened/fictional version trying to represent the same part of the actual code having the issue, so some syntax/other errors can be found in the code above, the issue is more related to my lack of knowledge of how the entity framework works and/or track entities when doing add/saveChanges

**Last update**
the SearchEntities method uses a different context, by "caching" the entities within a different context I was causing the EF to mark them as new-for insert, I just took the code of that method out to use it in the same dbContext where I was doing the insert of a new entity and that fix the issue, seems this is a very common issue, but due to it's nature every developer felt in the trap.

Comment: Have you made sure that your "something like" code also compiles and *generates the same problem*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no, sadly the sample I just created does work as expected, actually I see 2 of the "SomeEntity" in the db object, but the child entity isn't being added to the db object and SaveChanges method gets executed without errors, so the issue doesn't exist, but even in the "real" issue when detaching the child entity, the "current" causes the PK conflict on its table

Comment: i think the context will hold 2 values because the entity being tracked..

Comment: @RJ- Hi, yes seems that's expected, I just created a quick sample with 2 tables only and I see that behavior and the insert works well, but seems that the actual code having the issue is doing something wrong or maybe the model got messed up (lot of people have touched that app), in the case of the code having the issue, I also see the 2 entities, buuuuut I also got a child "status" entity added and causing the Primary Key constrain error, even if I detach the child entity, the parent "current" is causing another error because EF is trying to inset it (and already exists in the table)

Comment: i am not sure by detaching the child entity how application will behave. if only you do not need relationships then its better to remove It. Also it does not make sense if you do not want to save Status while there is one to one or anyother relationships.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: As far as I've read seems EF isn't tracking by changes, but not sure, will check actual code later today when arriving to work and will look for anything else that looks suspicious.

Comment: Do `newOne` and `current` have the same PK?

Comment: @aaron hi, not, actually "newOne"  is getting the max id from "SomeEntity" table, so it's actually a diff row to be inserted which gets only values from some fields/properties of "current" object, I just updated question with that line of code, thx

Comment: @GertArnold thanks seems my issue is something like that, will read it carefully later, I've seen other part of the application which does something similar also will check that and will update question if find something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that using entities which came from other dbContext is causing the issue the method SearchEntities which returns a generic list uses a diferent context.

Seems the outer context "doesn't know" about this entities and marked them as new for inserting them.

I took out of the "SearchEntities" the code to get a list of entities and that fix the issue.

Other possible solution would it be to detach every single entity or mark it as "unchanged"

thanks @GertArnold for your comment eventually what led me to the right path and solution.